# Space & Time Complexity of SHA-2

Tags: algorithm, hash, time-complexity, space-complexity, sha2

I am wondering what the space and time complexity of SHA-2 is. I tried looking around, didn't really get a straight forward answer. Can anyone help me out? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

For example, let's consider **SHA-256**.

Based on the description of the algorithm given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2), main steps are:

1. Initialise `h1,..,h8` (first `32` bits of the fractional parts of the square roots of the first `8` primes `2..19`).
2. Initialise `k1,...,k64` (first `32` bits of the fractional parts of the cube roots of the first `64` primes `2..311`).

Since their number is fixed, then the time complexity and space complexity needed for their initialisation is constant.

3. Break the message into `512`- bit parts and for each `512`- bit part do the following:

   3.1 Calculate a `1536` - bit number in `48` iterations by using a constant number of bitwise and arithmetic operations. Several temp variables may be used in between.

   3.2 Set additional `8` variables `a1,...,a8` equal to `h1,...,h8`

   3.3 Keep updating `a1,...,a8` in a loop `64` times by using a fixed number of variables and performing the fixed number of bitwise and arithmetic operations.

   3.4 Add `a1,...,a8` to `h1,...,h8`
4. Concatenate `h1,...,h8`.

As seen above, the time and space complexity of 1) and 2) is O(1). Then, for each isolated step from 4.1) to 4.4) they're also fixed. The only thing which is not constant is a size of the input message, and so the time complexity for 4) as a whole is O(n). The space complexity is O(1) because there's always a fixed number of temp variables used, and a `1536` - bit variable used in 3) can be re-used for each iteration.

Other **SHA-2** based algorithms like **SHA-512** or **SHA-384** have the same complexity since they're different mostly by the number of iterations in 3.3) or word sizes.

Thereof, time complexity is O(n) and space complexity is O(1).

Comment: Please, can you provide any citable resource for this?